# weird static appearing after application of solidify modifier

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do i fix this glitch, it just keeps happening. It is completely fine in rended view mode, but in solid mode this is what happens.

Comment: very urgent, going mad over here

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/